# Somebody wan to to send me eth tokens and asked me to send him fee first .. is this the normal way to do it?

Tags: transactions, cpp-ethereum, fees

Somebody wants to send me eth tokens and asked me to send him fees first .. is this the normal way to do it?

Comment: No. Probably they want to scam you.
In this scenario, a DEX or a smart contract that acts as a middleman would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

**Please be careful.**

That somebody can be a faker.

First, you didn't require tokens and he/she want to send tokens to you. In this case, normal way to do this is he/she need to handle the fee.

Second, if you want to buy that token, you must use DEX like Uniswap or Sushiswap which are verified by tons of people.

And also please check if that token is a honeypot.
You can do it easily by using this.
https://honeypot.is/ethereum

If I were you, I would not accept the offer.